# Websocket client call from several files

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have a file WebSocketClient.html which correctly implements a websocket connection to a server...
In this file, I have functions defined for each webSocket event, like this:

```
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) }; 
function onOpen(evt) { 
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED"); 
    doSend("WebSocket rocks"); 
}
function onClose(evt) { 
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
}  
function onMessage(evt) { 
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    websocket.close(); 
} 
function onError(evt) { 
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
} 
function doSend(message) { 
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message); 
    websocket.send(message); 
}
```

Is it possible to use this "WebSocketClient" file's functions from other scripts (PHP, HTML) to, for example, send information or messages to the server??

**i.e.**, call the "WebSocketClient" doSend() function from a new "User.html" file??

**i.e.**, use this "WebSocketClient" file as some kind of "API" for that specific websocket connection??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to use client-side script from the server? you can do an ajax request to get data from the server then pipe this through the ClientSocket... I don't really understand what your trying to do. The websocket is on the client.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a series of client-side scripts (HTMLs, JSs, etc.) that use that "WebSocketClient.html" file as a "callable" API to send different messages to the server through that very socket... It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Put this script in a js file (ie customWebsocket.js) and get it in User.html with

```
<script src="./customWebsocket.js">
```

Comment: Yes, but what if I include this line you suggest in more than a file (e.g., User.html, Account.html and Permission.html)? Would the 3 scripts be using the same WebSocket? Or would a different WebSocket be created for each one of them (i.e., 3 different WebSockets)? I need the only-one-WebSocket-for-all approach...

Comment: No they won't use the same. You are currently client side, so each script will create his own socket.

Comment: Yes, just as I thought. Thanks. But I need the other all-in-one approach, because a have to channel information from several scripts through only one websocket...